# How to sync my Dropbox files with a preferred local folder?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I installed Dropbox using following commands

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

Then I ran the demon with this command:

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Now I want to sync my Dropbox data with the `/var/www` local directory.
Is it possible?

Comment: yes @Naveen.I can setup it to the /var/www/Dropbox using interfaces

Comment: I have my dropbox synced with a local folder on my laptop which is then synced with /var/www/. It's really nice.

Comment: @Alvar how did you do that ?

Comment: See my answer! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Dropbox currently does not support syncing folders outside the Dropbox folder, [according to their web site.](https://www.dropbox.com/help/12/en)

However you can achieve this by creating a `symbolic link` between the **Dropbox folder** and the **other folder** you want sync, using this command:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Dropbox  **/path/to/another/folder**
```

So when you go inside `/path/to/another/folder`, you will be taken into `~/Dropbox`
Make sure the other folder is accessible after linking.

Answer (score 3):

According to their site https://www.dropbox.com/help/12/en you can't sync folders outside the Dropbox folder, but there is a workaround in Ubuntu

To get other folders synced into Dropbox you have to create a `symbolic link` from the target folder to the Dropbox folder

For example:

```
ln -sfn ~/Documents ~/Dropbox
```

Answer (score 1):

My five cents:

Using a virtual machine it is quite easy

First stop all the shares or uninstall dropbox.

Just create virtual disk and mount it in `/etc/fstab`.

Mount it to the `~/Dropbox`, i.e., `/home/user/Dropbox/` . Like this

```
/dev/sdb1    /home/blue/Dropbox/           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this setup on my laptop and often I edit the files on another computer and then test them on the laptop, takes 30 seconds for Dropbox to realize there are new files to sync, but works really great.

I created a symbolic linc with `var/www/` and `/home/user/code/`.

run this in a terminal to setup the link between your local files and var/www

```
ln -s /home/user/code /var/www/
```

Now add /home/user/code to your dropbox folder. Then when you edit the files that are in `/code` via dropbox they will be changed also in `/var/www/`.

Comment: True, but you may run into permission problems if you link to your home folder. It is better to sync Dropbox to your /var/www/Dropbox folder and then link to /var/www

Comment: @Jakke actually I don't get any permission errors, I've had this setup for half a year now. try it out if you don't believe me...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right command

sudo ln -s **/path/to/another/folder** ~/Dropbox

not this

sudo ln -s ~/Dropbox  **/path/to/another/folder**

because he want to Dropbox this /var/www folder outside his server..